# Filtering out a certain string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify the filterCandidateBySkill() function so that it filters the candidates by just the JavaScript skill.

I am new to javascript and not familiar with its syntax. If someone could help me out, that will be great :)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
const newCandidates = [
  { name: "Reece", skills: ["JavaScript", "Docker", "Java"] },
  { name: "Joanna", skills: ["Python", "Scala"] },
  { name: "Dan", skills: ["JavaScript", "Azure"] },
  { name: "Simone", skills: ["JavaScript", "Java"] },
  { name: "Ned", skills: ["JavaScript", "AWS"] },
  { name: "Yuhi", skills: ["PHP", "JavaScript"] },
  { name: "Jack", skills: ["PHP", ".Net", "C++"] },
];

function removeRowsFromTable(table) {
  const rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  while (rows.length > 1) {
    table.deleteRow(1);
  }
}

function insertCandidate(tbody, name, skills) {
  const newRow = tbody.insertRow();
  const nameCell = newRow.insertCell();
  const skillCell = newRow.insertCell();

  const candidateName = document.createTextNode(name);
  const candidateSkills = document.createTextNode(skills.join(', '));

  nameCell.appendChild(candidateName);
  skillCell.appendChild(candidateSkills);
}

function addCandidatesToTable(table, candidates) {
  candidates.forEach(candidate => insertCandidate(table, candidate.name, candidate.skills));
}

function filterCandidateBySkill(candidates, skill) {
  // INSERT YOUR LOGIC HERE   <-------------------------

  return candidates;
}

const candidatesTable = document.getElementById("candidates_example");
const newCandidatesTable = candidatesTable.cloneNode(true);

removeRowsFromTable(newCandidatesTable);
const newTbody = newCandidatesTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

const filteredCandidates = filterCandidateBySkill(newCandidates, 'JavaScript')
addCandidatesToTable(newTbody, filteredCandidates)

document.body.appendChild(newCandidatesTable);
```

Comment: how is this a php/html/css/regex question? there's only js here.

Comment: See [ask]. Generally, few people are going to be motivated to debug your code for you. It's best if you present your problem as a specific question. Tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and show us what results you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to get the filtered results. Filter expects a function that returns a boolean indicating whether the element should be included. `includes()` delivers that boolean value:

```js
const newCandidates = [
    { name: "Reece", skills: ["JavaScript", "Docker", "Java"] },
    { name: "Joanna", skills: ["Python", "Scala"] },
    { name: "Dan", skills: ["JavaScript", "Azure"] },
    { name: "Simone", skills: ["JavaScript", "Java"] },
    { name: "Ned", skills: ["JavaScript", "AWS"] },
    { name: "Yuhi", skills: ["PHP", "JavaScript"] },
    { name: "Jack", skills: ["PHP", ".Net", "C++"] },
  ];

function filterCandidateBySkill(candidates, skill) {
  // INSERT YOUR LOGIC HERE   <-------------------------
 return candidates.filter(cand => cand.skills.includes(skill));
}

console.log(filterCandidateBySkill(newCandidates, 'JavaScript'))
```

Comment: I want to add the results to a table, so right now without the function being modified, the html file will just display all the candidates with their skills, but id like the table to just display the only the candidates that have "JavaScript" in their skills, so for example:" Reece: javascript, Docker, Java " etc

Comment: @RyanLost I edited the answer to show how it would work with your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try simply with [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to filter out candidates that includes the **Javascript** skill

```js
const newCandidates = [
  { name: "Reece", skills: ["JavaScript", "Docker", "Java"] },
  { name: "Joanna", skills: ["Python", "Scala"] },
  { name: "Dan", skills: ["JavaScript", "Azure"] },
  { name: "Simone", skills: ["JavaScript", "Java"] },
  { name: "Ned", skills: ["JavaScript", "AWS"] },
  { name: "Yuhi", skills: ["PHP", "JavaScript"] },
  { name: "Jack", skills: ["PHP", ".Net", "C++"] },
];


function filterCandidateBySkill(candidates, skill) {
  return candidates.filter(candidate=>candidate.skills.includes(skill));
}

console.log(filterCandidateBySkill(newCandidates, 'JavaScript'))
```